# Average of occurrences of a character in a string array

Tags: java

I want to compute the average of occurrences of a character in a string eg if i pass an array ["hie","raisin","critical"],and i pass a target i then my method should return 1.6. How do i do this in java

```
public class Try {

    public static double averageCount(String[] array,char target)
    {
        double avg=0.0;
        String str;
        char ch;
        int total=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            str=array[i];
            total=count(str,target);

            System.out.println(total);

        }
        avg=total/array.length+1;
        return avg;
    }
    public static int count(String str, char target)
    {
        int count=0;
        for (int i = 0; i <str.length(); i++) {

            if(str.charAt(i)==target)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double avg=0.0;
```

Comment: How did you calculate 1.6? And what's your question? You posted a code, does it work?

Comment: Apart from being truncated part way through `main`, what's wrong with your code?  Does it compile?  Does it run without error?  What input do you give it and what output do you get back?  What output did you expect to get back?

Comment: @MarounMaroun : 5/ 3. I guess number of i's in total divided by number of words . It comes to 1.67

Comment: yea that was my imttent lostmind........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to add the total to the previous value.

`total = count(); //this replaces the original total.`

**use**

`total = total + count();`

**or**

`total += count();`

And average would be

`total / array.length //array.length would return the total number of elements in it.(here 3)`

Answer (score 3):

My Implemention:

```
String[]  array = new String[]{"hie","raisin","critical"};
Double[] occs = new Double[256];
for(int i = 0; i < occs.length; i++) {
    occs[i] = 0.;
}
for(String str: array) {
    for(char ch: str.toCharArray()) {
        occs[ch]++;
    }
}
System.out.println(occs['i']/array.length); // 1.66...
System.out.println(occs['r']/array.length); // 0.66...
```

Comment: @ Chetan Kinger  Charater is ASCII Code, so its type is integer.

Comment: @ code - panda My bad. Smart answer. Never thought of using arrays this way in Java (associative arrays) +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, you could simplify your count logic a bit as follows :

```
String[] array = new String[]{"hie","raisin","critical"};
String target = "i";
double count = Arrays.stream(array).map(s->s.split("")).flatMap(Arrays::stream).filter(ch->ch.equals(target)).count();
double average = count/array.length;
System.out.println(average);
```